# How to get config files for package after removing them?

Tags: centos, openvpn, installation

i have uninstalled a package(openvpn) and then deleted the config files in /etc/openvpn because of old files i don't remember creating, i wanted a fresh install. now whenever i do `yum install openvpn` the config files aren't put in /etc/openvpn or anywhere else. I am talking about the `easy-rsa` folders and the like. how can i include these in my install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of OpenVPN are you using?  If you are on 2.2.x or earlier, you should have the easy-rsa scripts.  Check `/usr/share/doc/packages/openvpn` and `/usr/share/doc/openvpn` for them.

If they aren't there, you are probably on 2.3.x+, which doesn't bundle the easy-rsa scripts.  You can get them from OpenVPN's Github:

https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa